# word count of each line in a script

Tags: bash

I have to write a script to read each line using a while loop and count the number of words in each line. So far i can get the total number of lines and the text for each on its own line. I am having trouble using the wc -w command to count the number of words for each line and display it. when i put it on the same line as the printf statement is gives an inaccurate count. I have to pipe the text tile to the script so it will count the words, for example: cat file.txt | word_count.sh

any suggestions?

code:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
line_num=1

while read line;do
  printf "line $line_num: $line"
  ((line_num++))
done
```

results:

```
cat imagine.txt | word_counts.sh 
line1: magine there's no countries 
line2: It isn't hard to do 
line3: Nothing to kill or die for 
line4: And no religion too 
line5: Imagine all the people living life in peace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf "$line_num: $(echo $line | wc -w)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfect, didn't know i had to echo the line and put () around it.

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to impress at the risk of getting caught for plagiarism:

```
 awk '$0="line"NR": "NF' imagine.txt
```